# Check if a file exists, given a directory to that file. How to debug?

Tags: c, server

So basically I'm given a path to a directory and should return `index.html` if it exists or `index.php` if that file exists. The thing is that I don't know how to debug this function since I'm only implementing this function for a much larger program.

```
char *indexes(const char *path) {
    char *newPath = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(path));
    strcpy(newPath, path);

    if (access(path, F_OK)) {
        if (access("index.html", F_OK)) {
            strcat(newPath, "/index.html");
        } else
        if (access("index.php", F_OK)) {
            strcat(newPath, "/index.php");
        } else {
            return NULL;
        }
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
    return newPath;
}
```

Does this look correct? When I run my program I get an error of `501 Not Implemented`

Comment: Without debugging I can see you don't malloc enough space for your initial string copy, so you'll be getting undefined behavior. And then you append even more to it!! And then in the cases you return NULL, you are leaking the memory you did allocate.

Comment: If the reason for creating `newPath` is to have a version of the `path` string that can be appended to, then you're definitely not `malloc`ing enough space.  Even if you're not, you didn't allow enough room for the null terminator, for that you'd need `sizeof(char) * (strlen(path) + 1)`.  (Note that the `sizeof(char)` isn't necessary since `sizeof(char) == 1` is always true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are going to concatenate `path` and `/index.html` into the newly allocated `newPath`, you must allocate it to at least the sum of lengths plus 1 extra byte for the null terminator:

```
strlen(path) + strlen("/index.html") + 1;
```

`"/index.php"` is shorter than the other string, so the buffer can handle the alternative concatenation.

The current code causes a buffer overflow, invoking undefined behavior, potentially causing the observed behavior.

Note that your code cannot work as written: you should concatenate before checking access, otherwise you check access in the wrong directory. You should also `free(newPath);` in case neither index file is found.

Here is a corrected version:

```
char *indexes(const char *path) {
    char *newPath = malloc(strlen(path) + strlen("/index.html") + 1);

    if (newPath) {
        strcpy(newPath, path);
        strcat(newPath, "/index.html");
        if (access(newPath, F_OK)) {
            return newPath;
        }
        strcpy(newPath, path);
        strcat(newPath, "/index.php");
        if (access(newPath, F_OK)) {
            return newPath;
        }
        free(newPath);
    }
    return NULL;
}
```